# How to present/push a custom viewController in lldb console with swift language

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, lldb

I want to show a viewController when I am debuging. so I want to fullfill this task with the help of LLDB. I have read some articles which give me advices as follows.

```
(lldb) e id $vc = [UIViewController new]
(lldb) e (void)[[$vc view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]]
(lldb) e (void)[$vc setTitle:@"Yay!"]
(lldb) e (void)[$nvc pushViewContoller:$vc animated:YES]
```

but if I want to show custom viewController not default UIViewController, the lldb will show errors as follows

```
Error [IRForTarget]: Couldn't resolve the class for an Objective-C static method call
error: The expression could not be prepared to run in the target
```

So what can I do to make it happen?

Answer (score 1):

As a work around, you could use `NSClassFromString()`:

```
(lldb) e id $vc = (id)[NSClassFromString(@"TheClass") new]
```

Comment: after tring, it shows errors: "no known method '-new'; cast the message send to the method's return type"

Comment: I updated my answer to include a return type cast, which is common to do with lldb

Comment: Sorry to ask again, after I executed the last command: e (void)[$nvc pushViewContoller:$vc animated:YES] I got the error: "error: Execution was interrupted, reason: Attempted to dereference an invalid ObjC Object or send it an unrecognized selector.The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation." can you give me more guide?

Comment: Does both `po $nvc` and `po $vc` work after calling `pushViewController`? Is `$nvc` truly a `UINavigationController`?

Comment: Yes It is truly UINavigationController, my project is language swift. don't know if it is depend on language.